Fix for java.lang.SecurityException: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver... in Flutter (Android)
Problem
I got the following error when trying to start a flutter sample app, in my case the flutter gallery, on an Android device:
E/AndroidRuntime(20352): FATAL EXCEPTION: SplitCompatBackgroundThread
E/AndroidRuntime(20352): Process: io.flutter.demo.gallery, PID: 20352
E/AndroidRuntime(20352): java.lang.SecurityException: io.flutter.demo.gallery: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
E/AndroidRuntime(20352):        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3069)
E/AndroidRuntime(20352):        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3053)
E/AndroidRuntime(20352):        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3036)
E/AndroidRuntime(20352):        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
E/AndroidRuntime(20352):        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiverWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:6157)
E/AndroidRuntime(20352):        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1913)
E/AndroidRuntime(20352):        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1853)
E/AndroidRuntime(20352):        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1841)
E/AndroidRuntime(20352):        at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:772)
E/AndroidRuntime(20352):        at com.google.android.play.core.listener.b.b(Unknown Source:27)
E/AndroidRuntime(20352):        at com.google.android.play.core.listener.b.e(Unknown Source:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(20352):        at com.google.android.play.core.splitcompat.m.run(Unknown Source:7)
(More stacktrace here)

I expected the app to launch, as it would on Windows, but it didn't.

Solution
I solved the problem by removing the following line (85 in my case) from android/app/build.gradle:
    implementation "com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0"
And changing the following line (line 8 in my case) from android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:
      android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterPlayStoreSplitApplication"
To:
      android:name="${applicationName}"
This does remove the Play Store functionality (not sure what it is exactly), but that isn't an issue in my case since I just wanted a sample app.

Play Core is actually deprecated, so definitely, removing play core, is the right direction
Other than that, you can try filtering your dependencies which transitively need play core, by referring to the steps mentioned here
